# Rails 5 Save polymorphic association parent form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, polymorphism

This is driving me crazy!!! I want to save in Rails 5 a polymorphic object within the parent object form, and I can't find a way.

I have a model Contact and it can have multiple polymorphic addresses, but I can't find a way to save an address on the parent creation form.

These are my models:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I would like to let the user to create just one address when he creates a new contact. I am building addresses on ContactsController#new

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
    @contact.addresses.build
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    if @contact.save
      redirect_to contacts_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
     params.require(:contact).permit(
       :name, :email, :mobile,
       addresses_attributes: [:country, :state, :city, :street, :code])
  end
end
```

And create a nested form:

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :mobile %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |a| %>
    <%= a.text_field :country %>
    <%= a.text_field :state %>
    <%= a.text_field :city %>
    <%= a.text_field :postal_code %>
    <%= a.text_field :street %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Create Contact' %>
<% end %>
```

It does not work. When I save the form I get an error:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007faac415a768 @base=#<Contact id: nil, 
 name: "John Doe", email: "john@doe.com", mobile: "666666666", 
 created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, 
@messages={:"addresses.addressable"=>["must exist"]}, 
@details={:"addresses.addressable"=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try permitting `addressable_id` in `addresses_attributes` of `contact_params`

Comment: @Pavan it does not solve it

Comment: Ok. Just for curiosity try permitting both `addressable_id` and `addressable_type`

Comment: Exactly same results. Not working.

Comment: These are the params sent by the form: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HyuwIHv4PEcDlpt48B7LTCwYzefT1XPwI6/V6RNF7Cd6iOQmO6IlbiDxxf637hvF9j1m+IKk3tPXwxfSYSHVoA==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"John Doe", "email"=>"jsjsjd@sjdjsd.com", "mobile"=>"666666666", "addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"country"=>"Germany", "state"=>"Branderburg", "city"=>"Berlin", "postal_code"=>"10407", "street"=>"Hufelandstrasse, 17"}}}}

Comment: Ok include `optional :true` here `belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true, optional :true` and check

Comment: It is not belongs_to, it is has_many and optional is not an option.

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: :optional is not an option for has_many in Rails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147048/discussion-between-pavan-and-juan-vidal).

Comment: Because addresses is a polymorphic model, you have to fill two extra fields in addresses model: addressable_type and addressable_id. Either passe them as hidden field in your form, or add them manually in your controller before save.

Comment: @Maxence: I am not so sure about that, if you generate the address on ContactsController#new it should not be needed to hardcode addressable_type and addressable_id in the form, neither in the create method.

Comment: Well polymorphic is a funny thing. This would be a good debugging to create contact first, then creating the address and inputting manually in the controller these two values. At least you know the problem is not coming from here...

Comment: Manually, using the console,  it works. I can create a contact first and then add an address without problems.

Comment: No I mean manually in your controller. removing the address_attributes from the params maybe. Creating the contact the same way you do. Then create some separate params for the address and adding manually the type and id like : `@address.addressable_type = "Contact" ` and `@address.addressable_id = @contact.id` then save @address.

Comment: just break your creation: contact first, then address instead of doing all at the same time. Then you can track bugs easier

Answer (score 0):

This "solves" the problem, but it is terrible to do it this way:

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  @contact.addresses.last.addressable = @contact

  if @contact.save
    redirect_to contacts_path
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: You assigning addressable_type and addressable_id explicitly. I knew this had to be done ^^ polymorphic is a bit weird

Comment: It has to be a way to do it without that ugly line.

Comment: Yep there may be a better way to do it but I am not very sure